What would this animal's meat taste like?
The animal is a flightless fowl that weighs around 80kg. It is an omnivore, though about 3/4 of its diet is made up of fruit, tubers, and other plant matter, with the remaining quarter being vermin like rats. The animal regularly fights and is extremely strong, about as strong as an animal its size could be.
What would this animal's meat be likely to be like, in terms of things like flavour and texture?

Fighting regularly, and being extremely strong, likely means a well developed musculature. Changing both taste and texture. Does this animal have a protective layer of fat? (Like a hippo). And how does it compare to for example an Ostrich?

VTC:Opinion-Based, and I vote that reason very rarely and only for one reason: questions that lead to the prohibited condition of all answers having equal value. Chicken tastes like chicken. Duck like duck. Goose, to me, tastes like greasy chicken (and that's a problem, taste is intensely personal). Pheasant tastes like pheasant. This is a meaningless question. Choose for yourself its flavor and texture. Your guess is, in fact, better than ours.

@JBH Goose, to me, tastes like greasy chicken That's because geese are close relatives of chickens that live in water, and due to their aquatic habits have a layer of fat on their body to provide buoyancy. Meat flavour isn't some random magic, it's derived from the physical qualities of the animals producing the meat, and as such can be derived from said qualities

The problem, Ichthys, is that if you want your animal to taste like chicken, you need to use the qualities that lead to a chicken flavor. If you're inventing a flavor nobody has ever tasted before, then asking "what does it taste like" is meaningless. You're assertion is correct, you just don't realize that it doesn't matter. Please explain to me what salt tastes like without comparing it to any salt. That's your problem and why I VTCd.

It would taste like a slightly large emu, because that is the creature you've described. Large, flightless, fights (females mostly), omnivore...

@WPNSGuy I knew that Emus won wars I didn't realise they ate their foes.

Emus (like Chickens, and Ostrich) are very opportunistic. They eat any meat they can get their beaks on. Which mostly means they eat insects, rats, rabbits, etc. This makes them VERY similar to the described bird.

The easy answer is it tastes like chicken. Everything tastes like chicken.

@WPNSGuy Or ostrich, the meat of which OP is likely to be able to actually buy, as it is available in many places.

@AmiralPatate Worth mentioning that chickens are omnivorous as well, and as well as grubs, slugs and worms, will eat small lizards and mice if they can get them.

@JBH OP's basically described a large chicken. Omnivorous, fights a lot. Chicken is an exact match. All that is missing is the size, for which problem Emu or Ostrich has the solution. Suggests OP find an upscale supermarket which sells Ostrich meat, and try it.

I'm thinking that it should taste like a more gamey chicken, maybe somewhere between chicken and turkey.

@Ben I can't read the OP's mind, can you? Are you absolutely sure the OP's is simply messing with us all and decribing a large chicken? Or, as is more likely the case, did Ichthys simply not provide enough detail concerning his imaginary creature? There's a reason we're supposed to be holding people to minimum question quality.

This question needs to be improved. Two big improvements would be providing details on the world and the environment, as well as what would be considered a meaningful answer. A chicken raised in an environment where its food is full of sulfur compounds will probably taste different from the same species raised in a different environment.

Having done considerably more reading it will actually depend a great deal on the bird's digestive adaptations. Most mammalian omnivores, like wild pigs and bears, have relatively recent herbivorous ancestors and a distinct "tang" to their flesh due to their relative inability to process the additional lactic and uric acids in their diets due to their consumption of animal matter, particularly stress hormone soaked muscle tissue after a chase.
Assuming they're not particularly well adapted to their relatively recent (on evolutionary timescales) change in diet these birds will be the same. The meat should still have a texture like a wild game bird such as Partridge or Ptarmigan, rather than that of the white meat of a domestic fowl but with a stronger, possibly slightly sour, taste. You might look for historical accounts from those who ate Madagascan Elephant Bird, they were a lot bigger but isotope studies suggest that they had a primarily fruit diet with various additions that their modern relatives don't tend to partake in.

The moment you typed "at a guess" you should have realized you were answering a question that was not well-asked.

@JBH For someone who is not a lifelong vegetarian that would be so, the reason I say "guess" is that my answer is based purely on biology without any experience of what I'm comparing.

Might want to change pork to boar. And what does bear even taste like ?

@nick I'm told like pork but sharper and apparently it's a lot better if marinated in vinegar.

This reminds me of the joke about the poacher telling the game warden that the endangered bird tastes like a cross between peregrine falcon and passenger pigeon.

@JBH Edited, heavily.

Cassowary, matches your description, tastes (to me) like a gamey chicken/turkey.
The muscles myofibrils convey some taste difference but more texture, hence the gamey 'sensation' since the 'combat' legs are holding up far more weight. Some descriptions I have read tend to use words like 'iron' flavour. The meat is tougher, but depending how skilled you are at cooking, it can be between a lump of rock/ hard leather, or pulled pork.
Tougher than partridge, or turkey on average.
Flavour, as per the comments above is subjective, I didn't like it, I felt it to be like deer meat, but dryer like overcooked turkey without proper basting.

Hard to say
Just because 2 animals occupy the same niche and eat similar foods does not make them automatically taste the same.  For example, the two most similar animals to what you've described are probably the Emu and the Cassowary, and what they taste like is as different as night and day.
Cassowary is an incredibly tough meat which requires days of slow cooking just to be palatable.  There is a fun Australian saying about Cassowary meat that says that you should put a rock in the pot when you boil your Cassowary; you will know that the meat is ready when the rock is done.
In contrast, the Emu is also a large, strong, omnivorous flightless bird but it has a tender meat that is often compared to filet mignon.  In fact, most people can not tell the difference between Emu and Beef.  Like beef, emu is typically seared and served between rare and medium rare.
Domestication makes a big difference
When animals are domesticated for food, they almost always taste better than their wild counterparts.  With a domestic animal, it tends to get less exercise and get breed for docility and greater body mass making its meat softer than its wild game counterparts.  You also control what foods it is able to eat.  For example, beef tastes very different based on what you feed the cow; so, we get different flavors of meat like corn beef, grass-fed, grain-fed, etc.  In this way, even if your animal is typically a bit gamey those unpleasant tastes can be breed and fed away.
Cooking Method and Seasoning also matters a lot
Slow cooking any meat will destroy nearly all of its natural flavors; so, even if your meat is really tough and has a strong gamey flavor, boiling will eventually make it soft and flavorless.  Slow cooked pork, beef, and chicken are all practically flavorless and get very similar final textures if simply boiled in water until done.  The only noticeable difference between these meats is how we typically choose to season them when they are done cooking, but if you throw a chicken mix into pulled pork, it will taste just like pulled chicken.
It is only when meat is eaten rare and unseasoned that there is a big difference between one terrapod and another.
So, even if you do go with a not so pleasant natural flavor and texture, there are ways to make it taste more or less however you want.

Here's some research on how meat flavor is affected by various factors. It is specific to ruminants, but extrapolation should be possible in many cases. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6154429/
